# Ruby round answer to 2nd decimal place?

Tags: ruby

Learning ruby and want to make a simple string where:

```
puts "A Honda Fit cost $#{3.98 * 10.6} to fill up."
```

The answer I'm getting is $42.1879999999995; would like the answer to round to two decimal places.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [Float#round](http://apidock.com/ruby/Float/round) method

```
puts "A Honda Fit cost $#{(3.98 * 10.6).round(2)} to fill up."
#=> A Honda Fit cost $42.19 to fill up.
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change the model of the data, you can just change the view, printing two decimals:

```
puts "A Honda Fit cost $%.2f to fill up." % (3.98 * 10.6)
```

Comment: I missed a `'` try now

Comment: ..at which point, I'd likely ditch the interpolation and use `%` on the outside, or use a temporary variable.

Comment: If you're using formatting, don't embed the substrings. Use `"A Honda Fit cost $%.2f to fill up." % 0.01 # => "A Honda Fit cost $0.01 to fill up."` And notice that you don't need `%.02f`, `%0.2f` is sufficient.

Comment: @theTinMan yes, better, it was to be closer to OP's code, but let's edit for future readers.

Comment: The OPs code was sufficient for normal things, but applying formatting changed how it should be written, so showing the cleaner and more idiosyncratic way would be better.